# How to continue multiple Kotlin Coroutines async operations even when one or more operations throw an exception?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Suppose I have the following code:

```
viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
  val async1 = async { throw Exception() }
  val async2 = async { throw Exception() }
  val async3 = async { throw Exception() }

  try { async1.await() } catch (e: Exception) { /* A */ }
  try { async2.await() } catch (e: Exception) { /* B */ }
  try { async3.await() } catch (e: Exception) { /* C */ }
}
```

What I expected with it is that even if `async1` thrown an exception, `async2` and `async3` continued to operate.

But the app crashes before any `await()` is called.

How can I do what I excepted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [supervisorScope](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/exception-handling.html#supervision-scope):

```
viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
  supervisorScope {
      val async1 = async { throw Exception() }
      val async2 = async { throw Exception() }
      val async3 = async { throw Exception() }

      try { async1.await() } catch (e: Exception) { /* A */ }
      try { async2.await() } catch (e: Exception) { /* B */ }
      try { async3.await() } catch (e: Exception) { /* C */ }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It worked :D. I tried to use `supervisorScope` before posting the question but I probably used it wrongly. Let me check it better ^^. Cheers

Comment: This video from Mitch explains `supervisorScope`: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9PYfYKRZ4Vo